# Is there a good way of using / embedding flash in winrt metro?

Tags: flash, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

If i create a flash game, is there any way for me to package it up so that i could sell it as an app on the windows market?

Comment: Did you try putting it in an HTML-based Metro application? I am not sure if it will work, but it's worth to try and should take only a few minutes to build a test app.

Comment: Not yet, I'll try it tonight when i get home though.

Comment: There might be later, when/if Adobe updates AIR to work on metro.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot host the Flash runtime inside of a WinRT application. This includes being unable to use the webbrowser control inside of an application.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2393055,00.asp), it seems IE Metro Style will not support flash (or any other plug-in), however in the same article it is mentioned that Adobe will release a "Metro Style" version of Adobe Air, so you will be able to deploy your flash app as a stand-alone flash app for Metro, [same as in iOS and Android for example](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/air.html).

Comment: Metro IE will support a baked in flash player, but it will only be activated for sites in the compatibility list

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices That does not look like a solution for the average developer...

Comment: it's not meant to be a solution for anyone, just clarification as IE 10 metro WILL support flash, be in a hobbled way that isn't useful for anything going forward

Comment: Excellent, i'll keep an eye out for this then. I'll update this when / if it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly - you can run flash in the desktop mode of the WinRT version of Windows 8 (not the Metro-style mode).  I'm surprised because I thought only Windows 8 pro desktop mode would support the flash plug-in.  Thought I'd share...